# How to get a coarse-grained op-level graph in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, xla, autodiff, computation-graph

I want to use tensorflow to get the full computation graph (including forward, backward and parameter update). I tried tf.functions, but the graph I got is too fine-grained, as many ops (Adam for example) are splited into smaller operators (add, mul, div etc.). So is there any methods that I can get a coarse-grained op-level graph? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use conceptual graph using Tensorboard, for more details you can visit [https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs)

Comment: @Tfer3 You mean I can extract the graph info from tensorboard event file? I have noticed the tensorboard conceptual graph, but I am not sure which APIs the tensorboard event file provide.